# Automating certificate management in Edge Browser through programming

Tags: automated-tests, ssl-certificate, certificate, microsoft-edge, client-certificates

When it comes to managing certificates in the Edge browser, the "Manage certificates" option can be found in the "Privacy, search, and services" setting of Edge. By opening the certificate manager, various operations related to certificate management can be performed manually,

For example:
option1: viewing certificate details and certificate chain details;
option2: importing and deleting certificates;
option3: checking certificate status,
and so on.

May I ask how to achieve automation of these operations through programming, including loading certificates, parsing certificates, building certificate chain, verifying certificates, obtaining verification results, and deleting certificates, replacing manual operations (options 1, 2, 3)?
In other words, how can all the available functions in the certificate manager be implemented through programming and run automatically through the program to replace laborious manual operations?

[image]

The ultimate goal of this issue is to automate certificate management in the Edge browser through programming. This involves performing various operations related to certificate management, such as importing, deleting, verifying, and checking certificate status, among others, through a program that replaces manual operations in the certificate manager. The desired outcome of this automation is to make certificate management more efficient, streamlined, and less laborious.

Answer (score 0):

The automation in Edge can be achieved using WebDriver like described in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp). But the certificates window is in OS level which can't be automated by WebDriver, then you need to use some other frameworks like AutoIT to access the window.

Comment: Thanks,it will be helpful to me, but the problem is not yet solved. Assuming I have already implemented using WebDriver to control the browser and using AutoIt to interact with Windows, however, WebDriver and AutoIt only replace my hands to operate the mouse , not my eyes. Now, I want to obtain certificate information in the certificate manager, such as the issuer, and save the issuer as a character string in a .txt file. So, how can I get the API that can read certificate information under Windows (Edge)? I want to obtain this information by calling API instead of looking at it with my eyes